# Create binary matrix from matching values each row python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have the following problem. I would like to create a binary matrix that looks like this (sorry I had to illustrate with Excel)

[image]

from this 1-column csv file:

[image]

Basically I want Python to read the column, compare each row and if 2 rows have the same value, the coordinate of that pair on the matrix would take value 1 and 0 otherwise.

So, if I have 10 rows, I would have a 10 x 10 matrix with the diagonal being all 1, also the upper triangle would look exactly the same as the upper triangle, separated by the diagonal.

Is there a way to do this in Python and Pandas/Numpy?

Thank you very much!

Comment: please copy paste your dataframe, not images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would just be to compare the array with its transpose in 2 dimensions, e.g.:

```
In []:
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'])
(a[:,None] == a[None,:]).astype(int)

Out[]:
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Note: shape of `a[None,:]` is `(1, 4)` and `a[:,None]` (equivalent to `a[None,:].T`) is `(4, 1)` this way when you compare them you broadcast the results into the square matrix `(4, 4)`.

Comment: Thank you! I got this error though: "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects". Do you know why it would be the case?

Comment: You will have to show your `pandas` code - the above is `numpy`.

Comment: Ah, I got it solved. Stupid me, I forgot to ".values" the dataframe. Thank you!